# LFSH ... what is '/lib/init' for?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, init-script, sysvinit

I'm trying to understand the init/boot process. My system is LMDE, so I presume it will be pretty much standard Debian in that regard. I believe I more or less understand the basics of the init scripts, `/etc/init.d/`, `/etc/defaults/` and so on, but there's this strange use of `/lib/init/` for a few of the scripts that look to me like they should be in /etc/init.d/ with all the rest. Can someone explain the logic of this? There's lots of discussion of `/lib/init/rw/` but none that I can find about `/lib/init/` itself.

This is all that's in there:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root 4.0K 2013-12-25//15:20:41 rw/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 1.3K 2014-01-21//07:37:07 vars.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 3.3K 2014-01-21//07:37:07 tmpfs.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  741 2014-01-21//07:37:07 swap-functions.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  17K 2014-01-21//07:37:07 mount-functions.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 4.4K 2014-01-21//07:37:07 bootclean.sh
```

Running `dpkg-query -S /lib/init` returns:

```
initscripts: /lib/init
```

Comment: Which scripts do you have in `/lib/init`?

Comment: Running `dpkg-query -S /lib/init` will give some hints where/what to look at/into.

Answer (score 1):

You can just open the scripts. `/etc/init.d` handle the daemons and any process that should start or stop during the boot or changing the runlevel.

But those scripts in `/lib/init` performs tasks related with cleaning .pid and lock files, mount/umount swap and cleaning the system between runlevels.

Comment: Yet, since all that is part of init, it seems that they should be under /etc along with everything else, no? There is an /etc/init as well. I'm just wondering what the logic of this arrangement is.

Comment: I agree with you. IMO just the init process use those scripts. That's why they put in a init directory.

Comment: I'm tinkering with the bootlogd system, thus editing all the init scripts, and it bugs me no end that I hafta make changes outside of /etc/init.d ... oh well, I tend to agonize over things like this ... Say, do you think I could move them and use symlinks in /lib/init pointing back to /etc/init.d? ... or would that reek havoc?

Answer (score 0):

Just like pretty much anything else in a `lib` directory, they are libraries.

In this case, each of those files is filled with functions and nothing else. They're sourced by other shell scripts to get access to those functions. Since the files are only filled with functions they won't do anything if you run them directly.

So to answer your question, they are a suite of shell library functions that are used by various init scripts.

Comment: I know what they do, what I wonder is why they are not in /etc/init.d along with all other init stuff. I've moved them into /etc/init.d with just links left in the old directory.  Ditto /lib/lsb/. Because I'm doing some work on those files, having the whole init script collection in one place is very handy.

Comment: Because they are *libraries*. That's why they're in `lib`. You can of course do whatever you like on your system. But as far as your question "why are they there", I think has been pretty clearly answered.